# While printing in console or saving a (big) data (came as an output in R) using sink() some of the last rows are getting omitted

Tags: r

I have an array `Y_obs` of dimension (200X353x5) which came as an output in R (I mostly use Rstudio in Ubuntu 13.10.).

**The problem:** `print(Y_obs)` does not display the whole array in console. It is showing the following:

```
 [22,]      0      0      0      0      0      0
 [23,]      0      0      0      0      0      0
 [24,]      0      0      0      0      0      0
 [25,]      0      0      0      0      0      0
 [26,]      0      0      0      0      0      0
 [27,]      0      0      0      0      0      0
 [28,]      0      0      0      0      0      0

 [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 172 row(s) and 4 matrix slice(s) ]
```

Then I went to sink my array `Y_obs` by using the following commands:

```
sink('CR.csv')
Y_obs
sink()
```

Then also it is showing the same output as the console after saving the incomplete data in the .csv file omitting the last 172 rows and 4 matrix slices.

When I tried the same in R terminal the it showed:

```
 [81,]      0      0      0      0      0      0
 [82,]      0      0      0      0      0      0
 [83,]      0      0      0      0      0      0

 [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 117 row(s) and 3 matrix slice(s) ]
```

**My question is:** How to save the full array `Y_obs` in a specified .csv file ?

Comment: see the help page of `write.table()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
?options   # the help page for the options function should appear.
bigger = options()$max.print + 200  # or add something larger
options("max.print" = bigger) # apparently RStudio sets max.print very low. 
print(Y_obs)     # the default on the typical R installation is around 10K
```

Comment: @hyde: I suspectyou are not an R user and may not have an open R console but I think the questioner can be assumed to have an open console. `?options` as the necessary reading for the questioner to do before further examining the code. That line is implicit advice to read the help page for the `options` function. I think copying material from the help page would be a waste of space.

Comment: Ok, now I can make enough sense of the answer even without knowing R, to know it probably is ok :)